# ReferenceError: index is not defined in listeners render. Extjs6

Tags: javascript, extjs

For the combobox field, in the edit window, I need to make the field change only one value up or down, like when creating a new record or editing it.

```
....
{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                name: 'status',                   
                fieldLabel: 'Status',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',                   
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                    id: 0,
                    fields: ['id','name'],
                    data: [[1, 'Новая'], [2, 'В работе'], [3, 'В ожидании'], [4, 'Закрытая'], [5, 'Архивная']]
                }),              
                listeners: {
                    'select': function (combo, record) {
                       
                        index = record.internalId;
                        filterCombo(combo, index);
                    },
                    'render': function (combo) {
                        //index = combo.getSelection().internalId;
                        //filterCombo(combo, index);
                }
                }
},
....
```

I do it using select and render events. The filterCombo function looks like this:

```
function filterCombo(combobox, index) {   
   
    store = combobox.getStore();
            store.clearFilter();
            store.filterBy(
                function(record) {
                    if ((record.internalId == index - 1) || (record.internalId == index) || (record.internalId == index + 1)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
}
```

1. When performing render, an error in `combo.getSelection () (ReferenceError: index is not defined)`. Why?
2. Is it possible to implement this logic more concisely, for example in ViewController in addItem, editItem methods. Ie to filter a store at the moment of opening a form for adding / editing, or is this an option not very much?
3. If to stop on the 1st point, then where it would be most correct to take out the `filterCombo` function that would not leave it in the `App.view.TestEdit` view
   Example [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2spj)

Thank